# Geoip: Select value from array in php

Tags: php, geoip

I have this [sample](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-region-by-name.php):

```
<?php
$region = geoip_region_by_name('www.example.com');
if ($region) {
    print_r($region);
}
?>
```

it will print:

```
Array
(
    [country_code] => US
    [region] => CA
)
```

I want to do this:

```
   <?php
    $region = geoip_region_by_name('www.example.com');
    if ($region) {
         print($region['region']);
    }
    ?>
```

But it shows a blanco record.

Comment: Code looks fine. where are you using this line, `print($region['region']);` ?

Comment: Instead of:  `print_r($region);`

Comment: `print_r` ans `print` have 2 different uses are you sure you are not mixing them up ?? can we see your full code

Answer (score 0):

Most likely  you don't have `geoip_region_by_name` installed try running the following

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_error", "On");
  $region = geoip_region_by_name('www.google.com');
  var_dump($region);
```

If you get output definitely the following would work

```
print($region['region']);
```